# Apple Magic Trackpad is working great, then randomly stops until hciconfig reset

Tags: linux, bluetooth, kde, magic-trackpad

I paired a Apple Magic Trackpad with my laptop through the KDE bluetooth system. It works fine until I touch it with too many fingers or swipe it too much resembling some sort of a gesture (or until the computer goes to sleep), then it simply stops ignoring any input, after performing `sudo hciconfig hci0 reset` it is automatically reconnected and works again, for a while ...

The same problem exists when connecting it from the commandline using `sudo hidd --connect` with evtest I found out that the problem is when a tripletap or quadtip is detected the event gets retriggered a gazillion times, this is one single three finger tap:

http://pastebin.com/KWYHbx5G

```
Event: time 1393907073.611256, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1393907073.647294, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP), value 2
```

If I turn the trackpad off the events still keep firing, not sure if it is stuck in the event queue or if it is getting retriggered in the bluetooth stack.

Any help to disable multi finger input or better yet, to make it work or how to debug it further is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It would be useful if we knew your version of Ubuntu, but the page I found is from an official Ubuntu wiki page.

It describes a method using `ginn` with `ginn-wrapper` (to auto-restart `ginn` in case of a crash) and configure it to act like Synaptics touchpads, and I have both a Synaptics device and an iMac, in which case they function *very* similarly, almost indistinguishably.

I hope it helps you out.

Here is the link: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/AppleMagicTrackpad

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/589617/apple-magic-mouse-frequently-disconnects-and-reconnects